# Creating new entry in array when updating existing value in dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, textbox

I have an array in which my Source and Destination are like this:

```
markers.push({
    "Location": "Chicago",
    "IsLocation": "Yes"
});

markers.push({
    "Location": "Los Angeles",
    "IsLocation": "Yes"
});
```

Now when i will create points with my dynamic textbox then I would like to add those all points in between source and destination.

Scenario 1: first dynamic textbox with input say for Eg: `abc`

```
markers[0]:Chicago
markers[1]:abc
marker[2]:Los Angeles.
```

Scenario 2: second dynamic textbox with input say for Eg: `pqr`

```
markers[0]:Chicago
markers[1]:abc
markers[2]:pqr
marker[3]:Los Angeles.
```

Now when I change the second textbox value that is from `pqr` to `lmn` then it creates a new entry in markers array instead of updating `pqr` to `lmn`.

You can check in console:

[image]

How do I stop that?

```js
// Code goes here

var cnt = 1;
var maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed = 5;

var autocomplete = [];
var markers = [];

markers.push({
  "Location": "Chicago",
  "IsLocation": "Yes"
});

markers.push({
  "Location": "Los Angeles",
  "IsLocation": "Yes"
});

function Generatetextbox() {
  if (cnt <= maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed) {
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class='fieldwrapper' id='field" + cnt + "'/>");
    var fName = $("<input type='text' class='fieldname' id='Txtopt" + cnt + "'  name='TxtoptNm" + cnt + "'  />");
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    $("#abc").append(fieldWrapper);
    var newInput = [];
    var newEl = document.getElementById('Txtopt' + cnt);
    var txtboxId = 'Txtopt' + cnt;
    newInput.push(newEl);
    setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0, txtboxId);
    cnt = cnt + 1;
  } else
    alert("Cant create more than 5 textbox")
}


function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i, txtboxId) {
  autocomplete.push((txtboxId));
  var idx = autocomplete.length - 1;
  document.getElementById(autocomplete[idx]).addEventListener("change", function() {
    var autoTextbox = [{
      "Location": document.getElementById(autocomplete[idx]).value,
      "IsLocation": "Yes"
    }]

    var markerLastIndexData = [{
      "Location": markers[markers.length - 1].Location,
      "IsLocation": "Yes"
    }]

   markers.splice(markers.length - 1, 1, autoTextbox);
   markers.splice(markers.length, 0, markerLastIndexData);
   console.log(markers)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="abc"></div>
<button onclick="Generatetextbox()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: your not checking the existing element which is getting changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you problem.

```js
// Code goes here

var cnt = 1;
var maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed = 5;

var autocomplete = [];
var markers = [];

markers.push({
  "Location": "Chicago",
  "IsLocation": "Yes"
});
markers.push({
  "Location": "Los Angeles",
  "IsLocation": "Yes"
});

function Generatetextbox() {
  if (cnt <= maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed) {
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class='fieldwrapper' id='field" + cnt + "'/>");
    var fName = $("<input type='text' class='fieldname' id='Txtopt" + cnt + "'  name='TxtoptNm" + cnt + "'  />");
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    $("#abc").append(fieldWrapper);
    var newInput = [];
    var newEl = document.getElementById('Txtopt' + cnt);
    var txtboxId = 'Txtopt' + cnt;
    newInput.push(newEl);
    setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0, txtboxId);
    cnt = cnt + 1;
  } else
    alert("Cant create more than 5 textbox")
}


function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i, txtboxId) {
  autocomplete.push((txtboxId));
  var idx = markers.length - 1;
  markers[idx+1] = markers[idx];
   markers[idx] = {};
  document.getElementById(txtboxId).addEventListener("change", function() {
var autoTextbox = {
  "Location": this.value,
  "IsLocation": "Yes"
};

   //markers.splice(markers.length - 1, 1, autoTextbox);
   markers[idx] = autoTextbox;
   console.log(markers)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="abc"></div>
<button onclick="Generatetextbox()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: In your output where is source and destination?

Comment: Textbox value should come in between source and destination like i have shown in my scenarios

Comment: or simply use this  document.getElementById(autocomplete[idx]).addEventListener("change", function() {
//markers.splice(markers.length - 1, 1, autoTextbox);
 markers[idx].Location = this.value;
 console.log(markers)
});

Comment: try now after change only we will update the markers

Comment: Your output does not contains my source and destination value and this dynamic textbox value should be in between my source and destination value

Comment: Please dont ignore source and destination value

Comment: it is included try again

Comment: Sorry to say i cant change it because changing it will require lots of changing in my code

Comment: Not including my source and destination value.you only check in your console

Comment: try now ... no time bye

Comment: can i ask you 1 question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85374/discussion-between-raghavendra-and-learning).